# Unique React Component for all SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm doing a component react and putting the "d" of several SVG icons in the state, remembering that the contents of an SVG is heavy, ie I want to center all my icons in one component, but what worries me is if this would be a bad practice.

```
export default class extends PureComponent {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        plus: 'M 25 2 C 12.309295 2 2 12.309295 2 25 C 2 37.690...',
        tags: 'M 25.125 2 C 24.824219 2.003906 24.523438 2.023438 ...',
        todo_list: 'M 13.21875 5.375 L 7.375 12.84375 L 4.65625 10....',
        calendar_15: 'M 12 0 C 10.90625 0 10 0.90625 10 2 L 10 4 L 4 4 C...',
        user_menu_male: 'M 19.875 3.3125 C 15.183594 3.417969 12.214844...'
    };
}
render() {
    return (
        <svg
            className={this.props.className || ''}
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
            viewBox='0 0 50 50'
        >
            <path d={this.state[this.props.d]} />
        </svg>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Not quite sure what you're doing here. If it's read only, pass the data as a prop. Otherwise if you're setting the state (which may change) from a prop, set the state based on the prop and then access the state. This weird access prop as a prop in state doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve switching between d attributes there is a couple options.

I think that the classic way to do this would be to use 'use' (don't do this): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use;

The React way would be to use conditional rendering. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html. For example:

```
export class SvgComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
              selectedSvg: 'firstSVG'
          }
     }
     render() {
         return (
             <svg>
                 <g>
                   {this.state.selected === 'firstSVG' &&
                        <path d="........."/> 
                    }
                   {this.state.selected === 'secondSVG' &&
                        <path d="........."/>
                    }

                 </g>
             </svg>
         )
     }
}
```

If you are going to do this, do not use strings; use constants that represent strings. for example `export const FIRST = 'first svg'`, and use that constant as you reference. you will thank yourself.